# How to call a function depending on the button pressed to show a div?

Tags: javascript, php, css, database, function

I'm trying to generate a set of N buttons, one for each row of a DB table, I need to show a `<div>` by putting his `style="display:none"` to `style="display:block"` when one of the buttons is clicked, this `<div>` will show a form.

Until now i got this:

home.PHP

```
    <div id="add" style="display:none;">
        <form action="#" method="post" id="form">
            <div src="close" id="close" onClick="div_hide()">X</div>
            Aggiungi
            <input type="text" name="soldi" id="campo" placeholder="Soldi">
            <a id="submit" href="">
                <button>Aggiungi</button>
            </a>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
    while($sezioni = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sezione_sql)){     
        echo "<div class =\"sezione\">
                  <a id=\"popup\" onclick=\"div_show()\">
                      <div class=\"pulsante\">add</div>
                  </a>
              </div>";
    }
?>
```

java.JS

```
function div_show() {
    document.getElementById('add').style.display = "block";
}

function div_hide(){
    document.getElementById('add').style.display = "none";
}
```

How could I call a function on submit that will update a determinated DB row getting in input an ID of the pressed button?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Non capisco il tuo codice : all the buttons are equal and do the same, make the form visible. If all the buttons are equal, you cannot know what button was pressed.

Comment: Element IDs need to be unique. You can't have `id="popup"` in every DIV. Use `class="popup"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pass db_id through javascript function.
2. In javascript function assign the passed db_id to the hidden input
   field in the form.

Passing db_id:

```
while($sezioni = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sezione_sql)){  
    $db_id = $sezioni['id']; // id from database   
        echo "<div class =\"sezione\">
                  <a id=\"popup\" onclick=\"div_show($db_id )\">
                      <div class=\"pulsante\">add</div>
                  </a>
              </div>";
    }
```

In Form add a hidden input field

```
<input type="hidden" name="db_id" id="db_id" value="">
```

In Javascript function

```
function div_show(db_id) {
    document.getElementById('add').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('db_id').value = db_id;
}
```

Comment: There is no need of adding id for anchor tag.